# Header file points to wrong package?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we have our own costmap package but didn't change the name of it.
So we have two costmap packages with the same name.

The problem is when opening with QTCreator, the include in `costmap.cpp` points me to the original installed header file.
But compiling is NO problem, although it shouldn't compile when really using the original header file!
So QT has something wrong here.

Next thing is that when we want to compile a package that uses the costmap package, it fails because of undefined references in the costmap package. So now, the header file is really pointing to the original header file and not to ours.

Any hints on what we can do to point to the correct file?
A `roscd costmap` points me to our package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134981/header-file-points-to-wrong-package?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're not really concrete in what exactly you have setup and how/where you are getting which errors.
So, here is what you should have done:

1. Ignore QTCreator (for now). It's just some GUI. If the setup is right for ROS, qt creator should be made to pick that up later on.
2. Assuming your costmap is an overlay of the ROS one, its dependencies should use yours. You can check that this is what actually happens during compile and link. `roscd costmap` being yours suggests this is correct. Whatever goes wrong you have to review explicitly. If you have a "compatible" costmap as your overlay that should work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0